Trouble with AI-generated tweets in Twitter browser extension when emojis are present in input field
I'm currently developing a Twitter browser extension that allows users to generate tweets and replies using AI. The extension works well, but I've encountered an issue when there's already an emoji present in the input field. The AI-generated text doesn't integrate properly in such cases.
Here's the relevant section of the content script responsible for setting the AI-generated text in the Twitter input field:
`
function setTwitterInputText(aiGeneratedText: string) {
  //Emoji making issue
  const elements = document
    .getElementsByClassName(
      'public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr'
    )[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('span');

  if (elements.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const element = elements[0];

  document.getElementsByClassName(
    'public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr'
  )[0];
  // .focus();

  console.log('input element: ', element);

  if (element) {
    const span = `<span data-text="true">${aiGeneratedText}</span>`;
    element.innerHTML = span;
    element.click();
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  }
}

What basically happens is illustrated here: 
The issue arises when an emoji is already present in the input field. Despite setting the content of the span element with the AI-generated text, the text is not visible, and upon posting the tweet, the text does not appear in the tweet, though upon selecting the generated text, the text could be seen there.
I've tried several approaches to resolve the issue.
I've examined the DOM structure of the Twitter input field and I've added console log statements to track the execution flow and verify whether the AI-generated text is correctly set in the input field,  apparently the span element does get added there with the AI generated text, yet doesn't give the desired results.
Otherwise, the extension works fine, whatever text is there or not. Emojis are the only thing which is creating trouble.
I'm seeking insights and suggestions on how to resolve this issue effectively.

why would you do that?

Try the deprecated document.execCommand, example.
